# C++ while loop not delivering expected results

Tags: c++, while-loop

Good day all, im struggling with my while loop. it will not continue after the first statment. It should take a series of Y or N user inputs and stop once the user enters N or n.

how the code runs:

[image: How it runs]

the code:

```
int main(){

    cout<<"Make a booking ( Y or N): ";
    cin>>booking;

    while ((booking== 'Y')||(booking== 'y'))
    {
        cout<<"Type of seat (E or B): ";
        cin>> type;
        cout<<"Price per seat: ";
        cin>> price;
        cout<<"Number of seats: ";
        cin>> number;
    }
    cout<<"Make a booking ( Y or N): ";
    cin>>booking;


return 0;

}
```

how the code should run:

[image: How it should run]

Comment: And where do you ask "Make another booking?" in your code?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: The types of variables is relevant. My crystal ball suspects that `booking` is an `int`. (And it's never too soon to stop using global variables.)

Comment: @gibs declaring `booking` as `std::string` wont make this code compile

Comment: True, but add at the beginning `char booking` works. I tried.

Answer (score 0):

This part of code should be inside the while loop:

```
cout<<"Make a booking ( Y or N): ";
cin>>booking;
```

So your while loop should look like this:

```
while ((booking== 'Y')||(booking== 'y'))
{
    cout<<"Type of seat (E or B): ";
    cin>> type;
    cout<<"Price per seat: ";
    cin>> price;
    cout<<"Number of seats: ";
    cin>> number;
    cout<<"Make a booking ( Y or N): ";
    cin>>booking;
}
```

Comment: That won't fix the problem of never entering the loop, though.

Comment: True, probably the point is that booking is not well define. But anyway that is needed to do what user13784854 wants.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char booking;
    char type;
    int price;
    int number;
    cout << "Make a booking ( Y or N): ";
    cin >> booking;

    while ((booking == 'Y') || (booking == 'y'))
    {
        cout << "Type of seat (E or B): ";
        cin >> type;
        cout << "Price per seat: ";
        cin >> price;
        cout << "Number of seats: ";
        cin >> number;
        cout << "Make another booking? ( Y or N): ";
        cin >> booking;
    }

    return 0;
}
```